# How to determine custom head for rules in Stanford parser?

Tags: java, nlp, persian

Stanford parser implement an interface for finding Head of rules, but it's special for some Tree Banks.
But, i have another Tree Bank(Persian Tree Bank). It has some different rules and has different Head. I know that [Interface HeadFinder](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/HeadFinder.html#determineHead%28edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree%29) is for this task. But i don't know , how to work with this interface. How i can write my rules and say to HeadFinder that witch head is?